# Mongo Db PHP Find the count of rows based on a specific field

Tags: php, mongodb, count

I am trying to display the count of items based on a category for a specific user email. 
This is my PHP code for the following

```
$email = $_SESSION['loggedInUserEmail'];

//Connect to MongoDB
$mongoClient = new MongoClient();

//Select a database
$db = $mongoClient->finchest;

$CheckEmail = [
    "CustEmail" => $email,
];


$collection = $db->History;

$Criteria = array("Category" => "Fish Skins");
$returnVal = $collection->find($CheckEmail)->count($Criteria);
echo $returnVal;
```

This code gives me the following error

> Warning: MongoCursor::count() expects parameter 1 to be boolean, array given in C:\www\FinChest\PHP\recommend.php on line 89

Please help me solve it, THANKS A TON.

Comment: What are you trying to with `$Criteria` parameter?  try this `$returnVal = $collection->find($CheckEmail)->count();`

Comment: I figured out the problem in my code. I was supposed to add both the conditions in the $CheckEmail array and then simply use the count(). Thanks alot. @Mani